# AG GRID - Make a filter based on 1st checkbox selection column

Tags: ag-grid

I'm trying to create a filter based on whether columns are selected or not. The selection is made by the first column which is created with:

```
            headerName: '(Checks)',
            headerCheckboxSelection: true,
            checkboxSelection: true,
            headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly:true,
            filter:'agSetColumnFilter',
            minWidth: 50,
            maxWidth: 50,
            width: 50,
            flex: 0,
            resizable: false,
            editable: false,
            suppressCellFlash: true,
```

Note: There is no Field associated. I use this column to select/deselect the rows only

[Ag Grid Filter Side Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PMPT.png)

When I go to the Side Bar Filter I see no values. I know how to make it display values adding:

```
            filterParams:{
                refreshValuesOnOpen: true,
                suppressSorting:true,
                values: ['Selected','Unselected'],
            },
            valueFormatter: (p)=>{
                    var x=(p.node.selected==true) ? 'Selected': 'Unselected';
            },
```

But even if I do that sill cannot make it filter for Selected/Unselected rows.
Any help will be welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake! I should have used

```
filterValueGetter: (p)=>{
    return (p.node.selected==true) ? 'Marcado': 'Sin marcar';
},
```

Now is working!